# Alternate location for Eclipse updates

Tags: android, installation

I have Android-4.0.3 installed on Eclipse. I want to create an app which is targeted for 2.1. For this I need to update the SDK for Android-2.1.

The problem is that my C:\Program Files(x86)\Android is not writable by network administrator.
Is it possible to install the updated Android SDK in any other path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Install the required Android SDK to any suitable location and modify the Android preferences in Eclipse.

In Eclipse, go to *Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Android* and change the *SDK Location*